# Moving frame (reference request)

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request

I'm looking for references (books or videos) to learn about moving frames in differential geometry. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following

$1.~$ "Lectures on Moving Frames" by Peter J. Olver.

$2.~$ "Notes on Cartan’s Method of Moving Frames" by Andrejs Treibergs.

$3.~$ "Cartan for Beginners: Differential Geometry Via Moving Frames and Exterior Differential Systems" by  Thomas A. Ivey, J. M. Landsberg (Amer Mathematical Society).

$4.~$ [Moving frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_frame) (including  the references there in).

$5.~$ "From Frenet to Cartan: The Method of Moving Frames" by Jeanne N. Clelland